# Using tweetsharp to pull my public timeline not returning any retweets

Tags: c#, asp.net, tweetsharp

I am currently using TweetSharp to pull in my public timeline to my web application.

Everything is working except I don't seem to be getting any retweets that I post.

Is there a way that I can get my retweets also?

Below is a snip of the code that I am currently using to pull in my tweets.

Thanks for any help or advice!

```
        var twitter = FluentTwitter.CreateRequest()
                        .Statuses()
                        .OnUserTimeline()
                        .Take(5)
                        .For(UserId);

        var response = twitter.Request();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I just answered your post on the TweetSharp discussion board.

I'll copy it here in case you don't check there ...

I can tell you that it is possible through the twitter api. The user timeline endpoint supports an 'include_rts' parameter that enables this exact functionality.

For example: http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=twitterapi&include_rts=true (if prompted for login, just hit cancel)

I don't know if TweetSharp has implemented that parameter or if it will get added. I don't think there are any developers working on TweetSharp anymore. I'm actually a developer from a different library, [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/), filling in the support gap.

Comment: Thank you Ricky. I'm going to check out your Twitterizer library the replace TweetSharp since it is still being developed and maintained.

Answer (score 0):

I forked TweetSharp [(RetweetsForListTweetsOnSpecifiedUser](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network)) and put in the code to add the include_rts as a parameter on those methods. Pass a true or false, 1 or 0 in as a value.